# Can I set the Start Menu in Full-Screen Mode to open "All Apps" by default?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, start-screen

When I open the start menu in Windows 10, by default it shows me the "Pinned Tiles". I don't have any pinned tiles, so this is just a blank menu.

Can I tell windows to default to "All Apps" instead?

[image: Image showing Start Menu with "Pinned Tiles" and "All Apps".]

I use the start menu in full screen mode.

Using Microsoft Windows 10, April 2018 Update [Version 10.0.17134.285]

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to do {Win-R} CMD {Enter} VER {Enter} then come back to the browser, click on edit above at left, and paste in your version of Windows 10? I ask, for mine (Version 10.0.16299.665) opens both Pinned Tiles and All Apps, so I wonder if this is version specific behavior? And, try the Open Sourced http://www.classicshell.net/ for more control over the Start button behavior.

Comment: @K7AAY i've edited the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the setting under Windows, Settings, Personalization and then under Start

It should be the secound option, something with app list....

Comment: it looks like this only works if "Use start full-screen" is turned off.